# Decomposition of differentiable function as a dot product?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis, homogeneous-equation

If $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function with $f(0)=0$, then $f(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{x}\cdot g(\mathbf{x})$ for some $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$.

I tried adapting the proof of Euler's homogeneous function theorem, but couldn't figure out a similar equation for a not necessarily homogeneous $f$. The reason I did this is because the right hand side looks like the result of differentiating $f(\alpha\mathbf{x})$ w.r.t. $\alpha$, where $g(\mathbf{x})$ is $Df(\mathbf{x})$. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ be fixed, and $\gamma_x:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be given by $\gamma(t)=tx$. Then
$$f(x)=f(x)-f(0)=\int_0^1(f \circ \gamma_x)'=\int_0^1 \langle \nabla f \circ \gamma_x,x \rangle =\langle \int_0^1 \nabla f \circ \gamma_x , x\rangle .$$
Define then $g(x):=\int\limits_0^1 \nabla f \circ \gamma_x$.

EDIT: As @zhw points out, this assumes that $f$ is $C^1$ due to the usage of the FTC. In his answer, you can see a different approach which handles the general case (which even relies only on differentiability at $0$ if you don't impose conditions for $g$).

Comment: This seems very natural, and I know that this probably seemed very natural or immediate in your head, but could you explain what made you think of this? This is more of a vague question, but what math heuristics or ideas went through your head while you were doing this? I'm just trying to gain intuition... I think this is what I was trying to get at with the homogeneous function theorem...

Comment: @FTem This is a very useful lemma (together with a few variants) which is quite ubiquitous. I think I've seen it for the first time in differential topology to prove the technical aspects of the definition of tangent spaces via derivations, so, to be honest, the idea seemed immediate in my head because I had already been exposed to it some times. I think this is the kind of thing you acquire via osmosis.

Comment: That works if $f$ is continuously differentiable, but we only know $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: @zhw. Indeed. I've added information, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @AloizioMacedo works if $f$ is $C^1$ by the FTC, but we only know $f$ is differentiable. The following will work in the general case: By the definition of differentiability, we have

$$f(x) = x\cdot \nabla f(0) + r(x),$$

where $r(x)/|x| \to 0.$ Now write

$$r(x) = x\cdot x\frac{r(x)}{|x|^2}.$$

Then we have

$$f(x) = x\cdot \left ( \nabla f(0) + \frac{r(x)}{|x|^2}x\right).$$

Setting $g(x)$ equal to the expression inside the parentheses gives the desired result. Note that $g$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\}$ and is continuous at $0,$ but it's possible that $g$ is itself not differentiable at $0.$